# Perl - how to unpack psinfo binary file on Solaris 10

Tags: perl, process, solaris, pack

I'm trying to get the info from /proc/psinfo file on Solaris 10. It's a binary file so wanted to decode it with Perl unpack.
Unfortunately, I'm having troubles with constructing the template for Perl unpack command. The psinfo structure is as follows

```
typedef struct psinfo {
int pr_flag;              /* process flags (DEPRECATED: see below) */
int pr_nlwp;              /* number of active lwps in the process */
int pr_nzomb;             /* number of zombie lwps in the process */
pid_t pr_pid;             /* process id */
pid_t pr_ppid;            /* process id of parent */
pid_t pr_pgid;            /* process id of process group leader */
pid_t pr_sid;             /* session id */
uid_t pr_uid;             /* real user id */
uid_t pr_euid;            /* effective user id */
gid_t pr_gid;             /* real group id */
gid_t pr_egid;            /* effective group id */
uintptr_t pr_addr;        /* address of process */
size_t pr_size;           /* size of process image in Kbytes */
size_t pr_rssize;         /* resident set size in Kbytes */
dev_t pr_ttydev;          /* controlling tty device (or PRNODEV) */
ushort_t pr_pctcpu;       /* % of recent cpu time used by all lwps */
ushort_t pr_pctmem;       /* % of system memory used by process */
timestruc_t pr_start;     /* process start time, from the epoch */
timestruc_t pr_time;      /* cpu time for this process */
timestruc_t pr_ctime;     /* cpu time for reaped children */
char pr_fname[PRFNSZ];    /* name of exec'ed file */
char pr_psargs[PRARGSZ];  /* initial characters of arg list */
int pr_wstat;             /* if zombie, the wait() status */
int pr_argc;              /* initial argument count */
uintptr_t pr_argv;        /* address of initial argument vector */
uintptr_t pr_envp;        /* address of initial environment vector */
char pr_dmodel;           /* data model of the process */
lwpsinfo_t pr_lwp;        /* information for representative lwp */
taskid_t pr_taskid;       /* task id */
projid_t pr_projid;       /* project id */
poolid_t pr_poolid;       /* pool id */
zoneid_t pr_zoneid;       /* zone id */
ctid_t pr_contract;       /* process contract id */
} psinfo_t;
```

but as I know nothing about C, I do have troubles with the representation of various psinfo datatypes in unlock template.
i also tried to view psinfo file with hexdump/xxd to see what data I can expect, but it didn't help me much.

So far I've managed to get this ready

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

opendir(PROC,"/proc") or die "Unable to open /proc:$!\n";
while (defined($_= readdir(PROC))){
    next if ($_ eq "." or $_ eq "..");
    next unless /^\d+$/; # filter out any random non-pid files
    open(PSINFO, "/proc/$_/psinfo");
    local $/;
    read(PSINFO, my $psinfo,1000);
    close PSINFO;

    my @psinfoInfo = unpack("iiiiiiiiiiIiiiiSSi2i2i2Z16Z80iiIIaa3iiiiii", $psinfo);
    print "'@psinfoInfo'\n";

}
closedir(PROC);
```

with the following output

```
'33554432 1 7871 4646 7871 4646 3339 3339 1087 1087 0 0 0 0 6291464 1 0 1522419148 159507010 0 113016534 0 0 top top 0 1 0 0   986003 3 0 0 0 924925'
'33554432 1 8323 9639 8323 9639 3339 3339 1087 1087 0 4116 2812 0 6291463 0 0 1522419159 626531984 0 39242598 0 0 processChecker. /usr/bin/perl -w ./processChecker.pl 0 3 134511508 134511524   986024 3 0 0 0 924944'
'33554432 1 8147 8146 2165 2165 3339 3339 1087 1087 0 6668 4060 0 -1 0 0 1522408545 333100499 0 513142054 0 0 sshd /usr/lib/ssh/sshd 0 1 134512284 134512292   984753 3 0 0 0 923830'
'33554432 1 21997 8153 21997 8153 3339 3339 1087 1087 0 2400 1504 0 6291458 0 0 1522410593 434583624 0 204410711 0 0 vi vi processChecker.pl 0 2 134511556 134511568   984753 3 0 0 0 923830'
```

but it doesn't really correspond with psinfo definitions. For example process name is truncated, time values are NOK etc.

I know, there is Proc::processTable available and I'm not trying to re-invent the wheel, but I can't use that module for various reasons, which are of importance.

I checked http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html, but still...

EDIT: based on @borodins suggestion using short C code I have also managed to get lengts of datatypes on my machine

```
Size of int: 4 bytes
Size of long: 4 bytes
Size of float: 4 bytes
Size of double: 8 bytes
Size of char: 1 byte
Size of pid_t: 4 bytes
Size of uid_t: 4 bytes
Size of gid_t: 4 bytes
Size of uintptr_t: 4 bytes
Size of size_t: 4 bytes
Size of dev_t: 4 bytes
Size of ushort_t: 2 bytes
Size of timestruc_t: 8 bytes
Size of lwpsinfo_t: 104 bytes
Size of taskid_t: 4 bytes
Size of projid_t: 4 bytes   
Size of poolid_t: 4 bytes
Size of zoneid_t: 4 bytes
Size of ctid_t: 4 bytes
Size of time_t: 4 bytes
```

Anybody?

Comment: The sizes of some of the types will change depending on the computer architecture you're using. I suggest you write a C program to print the size of each different type on the target machine using `sizeof(uintptr_t)` etc. You could enhance the same program to output the Perl `unpack` format.

Comment: @Borodin as I wrote, I don't know C. Can I anyhow implement your suggestion in Perl ?

Comment: No. You need C to read the releveant header files.

Comment: @Borodin, well then I'm bricked it looks like :)

Comment: You're discarding the possibility of learning a minimal amount of C so that you can put together a few `printf` statements?

Comment: well. Wouldn't know where to start, don't even know what header file is etc. Hoping to find some other solution instead of learning new language for one time problem

Comment: And you have no inclination or interest in *finding out*? I think you're in the wrong job. Even a little knowledge of C would stand you in good stead for many aspects of software development in the future.

Comment: Try http://p3rl.org/Convert::Binary::C - I cannot test, have no Solaris.

Comment: @daxim, thanks a lot, will try it.

Comment: @borodin followed your suggestion with C and have size of datatypes ready. Somehow Still not able to construct the TEMPLATE for unpack. timestruct causing troubles

Comment: You need to open a new question, showing all of your C and Perl source and output, and describing your issues succinctly.

Comment: `timestruct_t` is a C structure consisting of multiple fields like `psinfo_t`. You must unpack every field separately.

Comment: @Borodin indeed that was the trick. timestruct_t consists of seconds and nanoseconds both of LONG type. So what I was doing was actually OK :)

Answer (score 2):

To not confuse the audience with more editing, I will post the answer here. Its actually quite simple

1. I got the correct psinfo information from my system. On my system (Solaris 10 1/13 s10x_u11wos_24a X86 ) it was stored in       /usr/local/include/sys/procfs.h

   ```
   typedef struct psinfo {
       int     pr_flag;        /* process flags (DEPRECATED; do not use) */
       int     pr_nlwp;        /* number of active lwps in the process */
       pid_t   pr_pid;         /* unique process id */
       pid_t   pr_ppid;        /* process id of parent */
       pid_t   pr_pgid;        /* pid of process group leader */
       pid_t   pr_sid;         /* session id */
       uid_t   pr_uid;         /* real user id */
       uid_t   pr_euid;        /* effective user id */
       gid_t   pr_gid;         /* real group id */
       gid_t   pr_egid;        /* effective group id */
       uintptr_t pr_addr;      /* address of process */
       size_t  pr_size;        /* size of process image in Kbytes */
       size_t  pr_rssize;      /* resident set size in Kbytes */
       size_t  pr_pad1;
       dev_t   pr_ttydev;      /* controlling tty device (or PRNODEV) */
                   /* The following percent numbers are 16-bit binary */
                   /* fractions [0 .. 1] with the binary point to the */
                   /* right of the high-order bit (1.0 == 0x8000) */
       ushort_t pr_pctcpu;     /* % of recent cpu time used by all lwps */
       ushort_t pr_pctmem;     /* % of system memory used by process */
       timestruc_t pr_start;   /* process start time, from the epoch */
       timestruc_t pr_time;    /* usr+sys cpu time for this process */
       timestruc_t pr_ctime;   /* usr+sys cpu time for reaped children */
       char    pr_fname[PRFNSZ];       /* name of execed file */
       char    pr_psargs[PRARGSZ];     /* initial characters of arg list */
       int     pr_wstat;       /* if zombie, the wait() status */
       int     pr_argc;        /* initial argument count */
       uintptr_t pr_argv;      /* address of initial argument vector */
       uintptr_t pr_envp;      /* address of initial environment vector */
       char    pr_dmodel;      /* data model of the process */
       char    pr_pad2[3];
       taskid_t pr_taskid;     /* task id */
       projid_t pr_projid;     /* project id */
       int     pr_nzomb;       /* number of zombie lwps in the process */
       poolid_t pr_poolid;     /* pool id */
       zoneid_t pr_zoneid;     /* zone id */
       id_t    pr_contract;    /* process contract */
       int     pr_filler[1];   /* reserved for future use */
       lwpsinfo_t pr_lwp;      /* information for representative lwp */
   } psinfo_t;
   ```
2. the piece of code unpacking psinfo binary was ok. Only I didn't realize that timestruc_t has two elements, seconds and nanoseconds. Both of LONG type. (thanx Borodin)
3. Piece of C code, which is showing size of different data types used, is following

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <dirent.h>             /* UNIX dirs       POSIX */
   #include <errno.h>              /* error stf       POSIX */
   #include <fcntl.h>              /* UNIX file ctrl  UNIX  */
   #include <procfs.h>             /* Solaris proc    SUN   */
   #include <string.h>             /* Strings         C89   */
   #include <sys/stat.h>           /* UNIX stat       POSIX */
   #include <sys/types.h>          /* UNIX types      POSIX */

    int main() 
           {
             int integerType;
             long long_type;
             float floatType;
             double doubleType;
             char charType;
             pid_t pid_t_type;
             uid_t uid_t_type;
             gid_t gid_t_type;
             uintptr_t uintptr_t_type;
             size_t size_t_type;
             dev_t dev_t_type;
             ushort_t ushort_t_type;
             timestruc_t timestruc_t_type;
             lwpsinfo_t lwpsinfo_t_type;
             taskid_t taskid_t_type;
             projid_t projid_t_type;
             poolid_t poolid_t_type;
             zoneid_t zoneid_t_type;
             ctid_t ctid_t_type;
             time_t time_t_type;
           // Sizeof operator is used to evaluate the size of a variable
             printf("Size of int: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(integerType));
             printf("Size of long: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(long_type));
             printf("Size of float: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(floatType));
             printf("Size of double: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(doubleType));
              printf("Size of char: %ld byte\n",sizeof(charType));
              printf("Size of pid_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(pid_t_type));
              printf("Size of uid_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(uid_t_type));
              printf("Size of gid_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(gid_t_type));
              printf("Size of uintptr_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(uintptr_t_type));
              printf("Size of size_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(size_t_type));
              printf("Size of dev_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(dev_t_type));
              printf("Size of ushort_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(ushort_t_type));
              printf("Size of timestruc_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(timestruc_t_type));
              printf("Size of lwpsinfo_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(lwpsinfo_t_type));
              printf("Size of taskid_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(taskid_t_type));
              printf("Size of projid_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(projid_t_type));
              printf("Size of poolid_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(poolid_t_type));
              printf("Size of zoneid_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(zoneid_t_type));
              printf("Size of ctid_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(ctid_t_type));
              printf("Size of time_t: %ld bytes\n",sizeof(time_t_type));

           return 0;
           }
   ```